# UICollectionViewCell redrawing custom UIView sublayers with delay

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

I want to display something similar to the history in the Activity app, but for the sake of this question it's a simple pie diagram instead of 3 rings.
I created a custom UIView and use draw(in ctx:) to draw the pie.

**The trouble is that when I scroll and cells get reused, the pie persists in those cells for a brief moment before being redrawn.**

Here's how to reproduce this:

1. Create a new single view project
2. Copy paste the code below in ViewController.swift and Main.storyboard
3. Build & Run
4. Scroll down: you'll see a bunch of colored dots. Scroll some more and you should see the blinking dots.

Things you might ask:

- It's a simplified "calendar" of 10 months with 30 days (cells), and only the 2nd month has dots to showcase the issue.
- I add pieLayer as a sublayer of the UIView layer instead of using the layer directly because, in my project, I have more than just one custom layer

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {
   override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCell", for: indexPath) as! RingCell
        let ring = cell.ring!
        ring.pieLayer.radius = 15
        ring.pieLayer.maxValue = 30
        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            ring.pieLayer.value = CGFloat(indexPath.row)
            ring.pieLayer.segmentColor = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIColor.green.cgColor : UIColor.red.cgColor)
        } else {
            ring.pieLayer.value = 0
            ring.pieLayer.segmentColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
        ring.pieLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
        return cell
    }
}

class RingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var ring: PieView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        ring.pieLayer.value = 0
        ring.pieLayer.segmentColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ring.pieLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

open class PieView: UIView {

    // MARK: Initializers

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initLayers()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initLayers()
    }

    // MARK: Internal initializers

    var pieLayer: ProgressPieLayer!

    internal func initLayers() {
        pieLayer = ProgressPieLayer(centeredIn: layer.bounds)
        rasterizeToScale(pieLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(pieLayer)
        pieLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    private func rasterizeToScale(_ layer: CALayer) {
        layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale * 2
    }
}

private extension CGFloat {
    var toRads: CGFloat { return self * CGFloat.pi / 180 }
}

internal class ProgressPieLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    @NSManaged var value: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var maxValue: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var radius: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var segmentColor: CGColor

    convenience init(centeredIn bounds: CGRect,
                     radius: CGFloat = 15,
                     color: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor,
                     value: CGFloat = 100,
                     maxValue: CGFloat = 100) {
        self.init()
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        self.value = value
        self.maxValue = maxValue
        self.radius = radius
        self.segmentColor = color
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        super.draw(in: ctx)
        let shiftedStartAngle: CGFloat = -90 // start on top
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let angle = 360 / maxValue * value + shiftedStartAngle

        ctx.move(to: center)
        ctx.addArc(center: center,
                   radius: radius,
                   startAngle: shiftedStartAngle.toRads,
                   endAngle: angle.toRads,
                   clockwise: false)
        ctx.setFillColor(segmentColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
    }
}
```

Main.Storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="12120" systemVersion="16F73" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="NK3-ad-iUE">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="12088"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="NFp-0o-M02">
            <objects>
                <collectionViewController id="NK3-ad-iUE" customClass="ViewController" customModule="UICN" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <collectionView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" id="Sy5-uf-jPK">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="0.0" minimumInteritemSpacing="0.0" id="fkD-3N-K4T">
                            <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
                            <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                            <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                            <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                        </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                        <cells>
                            <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="DayCell" id="CXc-tU-7nQ" customClass="RingCell" customModule="UICN" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ic6-ea-Qzy" userLabel="Pie" customClass="PieView" customModule="UICN" customModuleProvider="target">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                        </view>
                                    </subviews>
                                </view>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="Ic6-ea-Qzy" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-8" id="9fj-SE-D1e"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ic6-ea-Qzy" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="CXc-tU-7nQ" secondAttribute="topMargin" constant="-8" id="Hnv-yr-EBN"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ic6-ea-Qzy" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="CXc-tU-7nQ" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="-8" id="I4E-ZD-JZf"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="Ic6-ea-Qzy" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-8" id="XOW-ao-t0L"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="ring" destination="Ic6-ea-Qzy" id="ZoZ-ok-TLK"/>
                                </connections>
                            </collectionViewCell>
                        </cells>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="NK3-ad-iUE" id="nAW-La-2EK"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="NK3-ad-iUE" id="YCh-0p-7gX"/>
                        </connections>
                    </collectionView>
                </collectionViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="6r8-g7-Adg" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-100" y="214.54272863568218"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

**Edit**

I might have found a solution, I created a drawPie method in ProgressPieLayer.

```
internal class ProgressPieLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    @NSManaged var value: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var maxValue: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var radius: CGFloat
    @NSManaged var segmentColor: CGColor

    convenience init(centeredIn bounds: CGRect,
                     radius: CGFloat = 15,
                     color: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor,
                     value: CGFloat = 100,
                     maxValue: CGFloat = 100) {
        self.init()
        self.bounds = bounds
        self.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        self.value = value
        self.maxValue = maxValue
        self.radius = radius
        self.segmentColor = color
    }

    func drawPie() {
        let shiftedStartAngle: CGFloat = -90 // start on top
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let angle = 360 / maxValue * value + shiftedStartAngle
        let piePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: shiftedStartAngle.toRads, endAngle: angle.toRads, clockwise: false)
        piePath.addLine(to: center)
        self.path = piePath.cgPath
        self.fillColor = segmentColor
    }
}
```

I call

```
ring.pieLayer.drawPie()
```

In UICollectionViewCell#prepareForReuse and collectionView(_ collectionView:cellForItemAt:) and it works

I'm using UIBezierPath instead of CGContext, not quite sure if that changes anything. I need to make sure this solution can be extended to the non simplified version of the projet.

Comment: If you can update frame inside layoutSubviews and avoid setNeedsDisplay it should be fine. SetNeedsDisplay proved to be costly sometimes with multiple layers in use.

Comment: Avoiding setNeedsDisplay put me on the right track, see above. I could put drawPie() in layoutSubviews() and call ring.layoutSubviews() instead of ring.pieLayer.drawPie(), but I'm not sure if there's anything to gain there.

Comment: The logic is to create one instance of the layer and just update the frame inside layoutSubviews, because all other ui elements generally gets updated there. So creation of object should be inside "init" or awakeFromNib methods. BTW with the changes you have done is it working fine?

Comment: Yeah it does work fine with those changes. Not sure what you mean by frame, the CGRect values stay the same from one cell to the other, it's just the pie's path that changes and needs to be redrawn.

Comment: ya, by frame I meant path. And it doesn't redraw completely.

Comment: Makes more sense :) Not sure why it works better though. Don't hesitate to post your comment (why it works better than needsDisplay would be a plus) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apple Docs: API Reference
>
> setNeedsDisplay()
>
> You should use this method to request that a view to be redrawn only
>   when the content or appearance of the view change. If you simply
>   change the geometry of the view, the view is typically not redrawn.
>   Instead, its existing content is adjusted based on the value in the
>   view’s contentMode property. Redisplaying the existing content
>   improves performance by avoiding the need to redraw content that has
>   not changed.

Basically setNeedsDisplay() redraws everything from scratch in the next drawing cycle. So the ideal way to do is create instances of UI elements only once, and update the frame or path whenever needed. It doesn't redraw everything completely thus efficient.

Comment: I ended up moving everything to UIView's draw(rect:) and don't need to call setNeedsDisplay nor layoutSubviews (which wasn't enough to solve the issue). Still, our discussion helped me rethink this stuff and investigate so I'll let this as the accepted answer. Thx